# Proof that the Omega combinator cannot be typed in System F

Tags: type-theory

I was reading *Type Theory and Formal Proof* by Nederpelt and Geuvers and in Chapter 3 about $\lambda2$ at page 81 they show how the self-applicator $\lambda x . xx$ can be typed by observing that $\lambda x : (\Pi \alpha : * . \alpha \rightarrow \alpha) . x(\sigma \rightarrow \sigma)(x\sigma)$ typechecks correctly. They then point out that, however, the $\Omega$ combinator still cannot be typed and that this fact is far from obvious. Unfortunately they did not provide any proof or reference to such proof and I am very curious to know how this was proved. Does anyone know?

In complete Parker-style, "I gave it a go" and this is what I come up with (I have never really been good at proving things so I might have made some mistake, especially since they said *[...] it's far from obvious*):

Let $S_1 := \lambda x . xx$ and $S_2 := \lambda x . xx$, I can write $\Omega := S_1 S_2$. If $\Omega$ is typeable in $\lambda2$ for some type $\tau$, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ must individually be typeable, with $S_1:\sigma \rightarrow \tau$ and $S_2: \sigma$. We already know that they are not typeable in simply-typed lambda calculus, and the only difference between that and $\lambda2$ is the addition of $\Pi$-types. **So if they are typeable now in $\lambda2$, it must mean that they have the form $S_1 := \lambda x: (\Pi \alpha:* . T_1) \space . M$** with type $S_1 : (\Pi \alpha:* . T_1) \rightarrow U_1$ for some types $T_1, U_1$ (note $\tau = U_1$). Similarly for $S_2$. But in order to apply $S_1 S_2$ it must also hold that the type of $S_1$ have the form $S_1: ((\Pi \alpha:* . T_2) \rightarrow U_2) \rightarrow \tau$ which contradicts uniqueness of types for $S_1$ (in particular in its domain type) because $\Pi \alpha:*. T_1 \neq (\Pi \alpha:*.T_2) \rightarrow U_2 $. Therefore $\Omega$ is not typable in $\lambda2$.

Is this a valid proof? I feel like the part in bold is the iffy bit. As in, I believe it makes sense "colloquially" but I'm not sure it's formal enough to be an acceptable argument in a proof.